# dask dataframe drop duplicate index values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am using dask dataframe with python 2.7 and want to drop duplicated index values from my df.

When using pandas i would use

```
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep = "first")]
```

And it works

When trying to do the same with dask dataframe i get

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'duplicated'

I could reset the index and than use the column that was the index to drop duplicated but I would like to avoid it if possible

I could use df.compute() and than drop the duplicated index values but this df is too big for memory.

How can i drop the duplicated index values from my dataframe using dask dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need convert `index` to `Series` by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), `keep='first'` should be omit, because default parameter in [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = df[~df.index.to_series().duplicated()]
```

Comment: it would work for a temp solution given that the column is not too big for memory but will be a problem when it is. Could you suggest a solution not requiring saving the entire dataframe or column to memory using pandas?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: I tried your code and got an raise NotImplementedError(key)
NotImplementedError: 0    True error

Comment: For both? aand if use `df = df[~pd.Series(df.index.values).duplicated()]` ?

Comment: @captainshai try using .loc i.e `df.loc[~pd.Series(df.index).duplicated().values]`

Comment: @Bharath - it is dask, so I guess there is problem with Series constructor. Hard to say.

Comment: @jezrael `to_series()` would work, `pd.Series` might change the default index.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_series'

Comment: @jezrael - i don't manage to get it working with your code, maybe i am missing something, could you provide with a single working example so i can test it and accept the answer?

Comment: @jezrael - managed to get it working the one with df=df[~df.index.to_series().duplicated()] worked! could you please clarify the solution and why keep = first is not needed and let's accept this answer!